# Poucas perguntas são reabertas

Tags: debate, perguntas, perguntas-fechadas

Há alguns meses sendo usuário ativo do SOpt e tendo usado o sistema de análises percebi que muito poucas perguntas conseguiram ser reabertas. Sinceramente acho que votei em uma ou duas perguntas que achei que mereciam ser reabertas depois da edição.

Claro, sempre tem aquelas perguntas em inglês que o usuário traduz e consegue reabrir a pergunta. Mas o que vejo quase sempre é o usuário editar a pergunta, corrigir um ou outro erro de português, alguma formatação e achar que já está adequado para reabrir. Percebo que eles não entendem que a pergunta muitas vezes precisam de mais detalhes e mais esclarecimentos para ser reaberta, o que é muitas vezes requisitado em comentários.

Tem usuário que repete a pergunta só pelo fato de não obter ajuda. Para usuário novo, é mais rápido reescrever uma pergunta do que corrigir um erro e esperar a aprovação para reabertura.

- Será que não estamos 'ensinando' adequadamente aos usuários (novos principalmente) como editar a pergunta para que ela possa ser reaberta?
- O que podemos fazer para ajudar as pessoas a editarem melhor suas perguntas para que tenham mais chances de ser aberta novamente?

Vi várias perguntas que seriam ótimas se o fossem editadas para atender o objetivo do site, mas que ficaram fechadas por falta de edição adequada.

Comment: Tem usuário que repete a pergunta só pelo fato de não obter ajuda, imagina quando a questão é fechada... Para usuário novo, é mais rápido reescrever uma pergunta do que corrigir um erro e esperar a aprovação para reabertura. O pior caso é o abandono pela 'experiência ruim' do próprio mau uso.

Comment: @PapaCharlie É verdade, bem lembrado. Se me permite vou colocar isso na pergunta.

Comment: Fique à vontade :)

Answer (score 11):

Não contradirei as demais respostas totalmente, porque realmente são problemas que existem, porém gostaria de acrescentar alguns pontos a mais e incentivar uma ação diferente dos usuários.

## Diferentes conceitos sobre o escopo

Muitas perguntas são fechadas por usuários que tem uma noção mais restrita do escopo, pois elas ficam no limiar do que seria "programação".

Por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21814/como-inicializar-o-postgresql-com-o-ubuntu) levou 4 meses para ser fechada. Ela é sobre inicializar o PostgreSQL com o sistema.

Já foi muito discutido aqui sobre questões que envolvem coisas comuns a programadores, mas não são diretamente sobre programação. Não há um consenso exato e na minha opinião cada caso é um caso.

Para esta pergunta em específico, para mim faz todo sentido manter ela no site porque pode ser útil para muitos programadores resolvendo um problema específico comum a muitos deles.

Além disso, provavelmente se a pergunta fosse sobre *como configurar o meu aplicativo na inicialização do sistema* a pergunta não teria sido fechada.

## Diferentes interpretações

Outras perguntas são fechadas porque usuários a entendem de forma diferente.

Por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21181/dicas-para-se-transformar-c%C3%B3digo-procedural-em-orientado-a-objeto) envolve questões conceituais de conversão de código procedural para OO. Ela tem duas respostas interessantes, mas foi fechada após uma semana.

Alguns usuários acharam que ela é ampla. Bem, mas é só ver pelas respostas que é bem possível estabelecer alguns princípios básicos para o que o AP queria.

Na pior das hipóteses, a questão poderia ser editada para falar sobre *princípios básicos para conversão de código procedural para OO*.

Nesses casos, entendo que a pergunta não pode ser considerada ampla porque alguns acham que a resposta deve ser longa. Na vida real, existem assuntos que são brevemente descritos em notas, revisados em artigos ou aprofundados em livros. Existem vários níveis de detalhe e claramente o AP queria em alto nível, sem aprofundamento, portanto a resposta pode ser sucinta sem problemas.

Uma pergunta ampla, creio, seria quando pudessem surgir muitas respostas diferentes e nenhuma delas realmente atenderia aos requisitos da pergunta completamente.

Mais uma vez, cada caso é diferente dos demais e há os casos limítrofes.

## Orientações ortogonais

Algumas perguntas fechadas simplesmente não possuem orientação para o AP. Em outras, a orientação não ensina o usuário a usar o site.

Por exemplo, [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22278/problemas-com-l%C3%B3gica-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) o usuário pede ajuda para como escrever código. Entendo perfeitamente que o SOpt não é um lugar para se aprender a programar, entretanto o usuário chegou a postar um código e poderia ser dada orientação específica e benéfica para muitas pessoas.

Só para exemplificar, a pergunta poderia ser editada para focar em um problema específico, descrevendo o enunciado, colocando o código com problemas e solicitando ajuda para entender como escrever o algoritmo corretamente.

Isso ocorre várias vezes por aqui sem nenhum problema, era só uma questão de guiar um iniciante "perdido" para se concentrar em algo específico ao invés de tentar resolver todos os problemas de uma só vez.

## Pedido de Material

Emendando o tópico anterior, onde o AP pediu material para estudo, muita gente critica, negativa e vota para fechar por causa disso.

Ora, a não ser que a pergunta seja 100% um pedido de material, não há razão no universo para fechá-la. Nós não achamos que boas respostas fornecem referências e links? Então devemos evitar preconceito com perguntas que, além de perguntar algo, peçam também algum material extra para se aprofundar no assunto. Muitas vezes o AP pede esses materiais para demonstrar boa vontade de pesquisar por si mesmo.

Além disso, um conceito errado que alguns iniciantes possuem é que existe algum curso, livro, apostila, etc. que vai ensinar tudo o que eles precisam saber de uma vez só e assim ele não vai mais precisar pedir ajuda.

Mas todos nós sabemos que o conhecimento sobre programação somente se consolida com o exercício e a experiência, resolvendo um problema após o outro. Então é importante orientar o usuário, por exemplo, dizendo que é melhor ele se concentrar no problema imediato, descrevendo-o adequadamente e entendo bem sua solução.

## "*Não tem um detalhe que eu gostaria que tivesse*"

Outras perguntas são fechadas porque o AP não informou algum detalhe específico.

Por exemplo, [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16396/inserir-imagem-no-banco-de-dados) foi fechada, creio eu, porque o AP não disse qual banco de dados ele estava usando.

Mas porque não daria para responder de forma genérica ou orientar o AP? Aliás, isso foi feito e muito bem. As respostas são boas, há votos positivos e tudo o mais. Certamente isso beneficia a internet e a comunidade de programação.

Será que o tipo de campo par armazenar imagem e os conceitos variam tanto assim entre os principais SGBDRs?

## "*Não entendi e não acho que ninguém deveria ter entendido...*"

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46711/tag-a-href-sem-alterar-a-barra-de-localiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o) está mal escrita, mas consigo entender perfeitamente a intenção do AP, inclusive há respostas boas e simples ali.

Este seria o caso de editar a pergunta para deixá-la mais clara e fazer sentido com as respostas. Caso o AP não concordasse, ele poderia esclarecer por si mesmo.

## Não caia na rotina

Um perigo muito grande que *devemos* evitar aqui no SOpt é que a comunidade envolvida com o site há certo tempo acabe se desgastando com as perguntas "ruins" e sinta-se no dever de fechá-las ao menor sinal de *<preencha aqui qualquer coisa que aparece repetidamente no site e que você não aguenta mais>*.

Devemos nos esforçar para não engatar os dedinhos no "fechar automático".

## Seja paciente com as crianças

Quando envelhecemos deveríamos ficar mais pacientes, mas na prática acabamos é perdendo a paciência com a "juventude" que comete os mesmos erros vez após vez.

Por mais que nos esforcemos nunca conseguiremos fazer com que os novos usuários do site consigam fazer boas perguntas e respostas logo de início.

Portanto, se você é jovem ainda (no coração), crie o hábito de ajudar os novatos de forma ativa e positiva. Se deixarmos as emoções tomarem conta, logo estaremos jogando nossas frustrações em cima de quem nem conhecemos e julgamos "inferior".

Eu mesmo levei uns 6 meses perguntando e respondendo para entender "qualé" a do site (e ainda hoje tenho as minhas dúvidas se entendo de verdade).

## Conclusões

Não creio que seja a maioria, mas **boa parte** das perguntas fechadas poderiam ser reabertas sem problemas ao tomar uma das ações abaixo:

1. Orientar especificamente o usuário em como ele deve editar a pergunta
2. Gastar um tempinho a mais para entender e editar a pergunta
3. Reconsiderar se ela foi injustamente fechada ou mal interpretada

## Faça sua parte

É possível melhorar a qualidade do site sem que seja necessário fechar todas as perguntas com algum problema.

[Pesquise pelas perguntas fechadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes) e certamente há o que melhorar editando, orientado com comentários ou mesmo votando para reabrir.

Comment: Eu concordo com tudo, mas queria ter um jeito de repetir mil vezes o ponto 2... "Gastar um tempinho a mais para entender e editar a pergunta", `Gastar um tempinho a mais para entender e editar a pergunta`, *Gastar um tempinho a mais para entender e editar a pergunta*, **Gastar um tempinho a mais para entender e editar a pergunta**. Existem várias perguntas fechadas em que os comentários mostram *claramente* que nós sabíamos como melhorar a pergunta, mas esperávamos que o AP fizesse isso. Não sei como ou porque isso seria benéfico ao AP ou à nossa comunidade.

Comment: A parte do "*<preencha aqui qualquer coisa que aparece repetidamente no site e que você não aguenta mais>*" não estava sendo renderizada. Corrigi isso.

Comment: @Gabe, utluiz, Acabei de entrar para ver questões para reabrir, mas as TAGS são aquém do meu conhecimento. Devo priorizar a abertura de questões visando diminuir o tempo entre edição e aprovação? No caso, meu critério seria analisar a relevância da edição e não o conteúdo em si...

Comment: Fantástica resposta. :)

Comment: @PapaCharlie É complicado decidir quando não se tem conhecimento suficiente para julgar uma questão. Se a edição fosse relevante, eu preferiria reabrir mesmo que não estivesse 100% perfeita. Isso traria mais atenção à pergunta ainda que seja para solicitar mais alguma melhoria. Entretanto, caso fique na dúvida, sempre dá para "pular" e deixar outros usuários votarem. Algo que eu **nunca** recomendo é *votar para fechar ou manter fechada uma pergunta quando você não entende do assunto*.

Comment: Engraçado que são perguntas que eu indiquei para fechar... #SouSempreOCristoDoMeta :P

Comment: @utluiz eu acho que as perguntas, quando não são claras por algum motivo devam ser fechadas para evitar respostas "eu acho" e o AP alertado. Eu não vou editar perguntas que não tenho a certeza da intenção do AP. Se calhar sou eu que estou errado, mas é a minha opinião.

Comment: De qualquer forma levas mais um pela iniciativa 1,2 e 3.

Comment: @JorgeB. Claro que esse é um caso que depende de muitas outras variáveis, mas se você tiver na cabeça uma edição que não tem certeza se corresponde à intenção do autor *mas* que deixaria a pergunta muito mais clara, acho melhor fazer a edição. Edições são contínuas e reversíveis. Se sua edição piorar a pergunta de alguma maneira, outras pessoas - incluindo a AP - podem consertar. É preferível um pouco de "confusão  a uma pergunta abandonada e sem apelo.

Comment: @Gabe o problema é que aparecerão respostas consoante a minha edição. Se depois o AP reverter ou editar ficará uma confusão de respostas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Nenhuma das duas soluções é perfeita, mas o mesmo princípio de melhoria constante se aplica às respostas. A não ser que sua edição descaracterize *completamente* a pergunta, as respostas não vão desvirtuar muito do que provavelmente era pretendido pela AP.

Comment: Não concordo @Gabe. Na maioria das vezes o que vejo são respostas de "eu acho", o que acontece é que fica uma salgalhada, uma qualidade muito baixa. Eu como considero a qualidade um dos fatores mais importantes, acho que perguntas assim deveriam ser fechadas. E só reabertas quando uma ou mais edições a deixa-se com qualidade satisfatória. Já se sabe que medir qualidade é complicado. Mas as vezes é bem fácil, pelo menos para mim, fechar uma pergunta que eu considere que vá criar mais ruído que outra coisa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Há casos e casos. Algumas perguntas não tem muita salvação, e o fechamento é o melhor caminho. Mas algumas, as que você tem *quase certeza* de que consegue editar, é melhor editar.

Comment: Mas não se trata de salvação ou não. Quase todas têm salvação. O problema é deixar as perguntas abertas a espera de salvação...

Comment: @JorgeB. Se a sua edição salvar, ela não precisa esperar salvação. O tópico aqui é que poucas perguntas são reabertas, e poucas perguntas são reabertas porque poucas edições no site são profundas o suficiente pra salvar as perguntas. Há muita formatação e gramática, mas no geral pouca alteração no teor das perguntas. E isso é algo que faz toda a diferença.

Comment: @JorgeB. Há uma distinção grande entre atos que "não deixam o site piorar" e atos que "melhoram o site".

Comment: Ah agora entendi. E parece-me muito boa ideia.

Answer (score 9):

Idealmente nenhuma pergunta deveria ser reaberta, pelo simples fato que se se dá para resolver o problema, então ele deveria ser resolvido antes de fechar.

Mas eu entendo que isto é algo difícil de alcançar.

Se você vê ótimas perguntas que podem ser adequadas com uma simples edição, faça a edição e aí ninguém precisa fechá-las. Mas acho que o problema é outro.

Nós não estamos conseguindo ensinar os usuários a melhorar suas perguntas. Mas tenho minhas dúvidas se é falha nossa. Pode ser pontualmente mas vejo na maior parte dos casos um esforço sendo feito para ajudar. O problema é que na maior parte dos casos não basta uma simples edição. Só o autor da pergunta consegue resolver o problema. E mesmo ele sendo direcionado para fazer, ele não consegue. Algumas vezes é porque ele é teimoso e quer as coisas do jeito dele, algumas vezes ele não tem capacidade para entender o próprio problema, conseguir as informações necessárias. Ou seja, ele é um péssimo usuário de computadores e está tentando programar. Fica difícil.

Eu já perdi mais de uma hora tentando fazer um usuário do *site* dar informações suficientes até desistir. Eu podia estar usando esse tempo para fazer algo mais útil em outras perguntas. Em determinado momento ajudar o usuário se torna o ruído, que é o que a plataforma tenta isolar.

Reforço que ajudar o usuário salvar uma pergunta é bom, sempre que podemos devemos tentar ajudar ativamente (fazendo algo na pergunta) ou passivamente (dando instruções do que ele precisa mudar). Mas tem que saber a hora que não dá mais para fazer nada. Quando o autor está drenando a energia positiva do *site* em seu favor de forma individualista. Senão vira fórum.

Então não sei responder uma das partes da sua pergunta. Eu acho que no geral os usuários mais ativos já ajudam no que podem. Acho que os usuários já ajudam bastante porque há a ilusão de que não incomodar os novatos com regras úteis (não estou falando de regra pela regra que é obviamente ruim) vão fazer eles se afastarem. O que afasta é ele não conseguir participar e ele não vai conseguir se ele não ajuda também. Fora os casos que a pessoa, no fundo, não quer ajudar a ser ajudado, tem os que não sabem como ajudar. Aí faltam facilidades no *site* para a pessoa aprender a melhor forma.

Muitas pessoas não sabem se comportar em comunidade, não sabem pedir ajuda, não sabem organizar as próprias ideias, não conseguem definir seus problemas, não conseguem seguir exemplos, não conseguem usar a UI do *site*, não conseguem nem perceber que o *site* usa palavras em português, muitas vezes não conseguem escrever o português (e claro que não estou falando de ortografia e gramática perfeita, só de ser minimamente compreensível) e ele não consegue entender como fazer o MCVE, o que é um grande problema para quem pretende ser programador. Elas têm problemas que vão além do uso do *site*.

E nem falei do fato que alguns acham que estão fazendo um favor em vir aqui pedir ajuda quando é o oposto. Eu realmente não sei como resolver estes casos. A maioria dos casos que dá para solucionar estão sendo solucionados. Alguns com mais ruído do que deveria. Chega se gastar várias vezes mais energia fazendo a pessoa conseguir deixar o problema compreensível do que respondendo a pergunta.

Ensinar essas pessoas dá muito trabalho. Não sei se ajudaria muito mas ela teria que ler muita coisa. E ela não quer ler nada. A própria ideia da plataforma é não oferecer muita fricção para a pessoa iniciar sua participação. Mas na prática gera fricção durante a participação. Não adianta, só existem duas hipóteses, ou deixa as pessoas fazerem o que elas querem ou ignora quem não quer ou não consegue se adaptar para benefício próprio. E isto não é o mesmo que dizer que não devemos ajudá-las.

Infelizmente não sei como resolver um problema de [má educação](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/) - em todos os sentidos. Pode ser só uma impressão mas me parece que é mais fácil compreender perguntas em inglês de quem não fala inglês do que perguntas em português de quem fala português.

Existe uma falha na escola que não mais ensina as pessoas se comunicar e resolver problemas, que são as duas coisas fundamentais que a pessoa deve saber. E existe um comportamento, principalmente entre os mais novos, que eles acham que são dádivas que precisam ter todas suas necessidades satisfeitas sem que eles precisem colaborar em nada. E quando as duas coisas se misturam, temos um problema grave e insolúvel.

Note que estou diferenciando dos casos da pessoa não entender como o nosso *site* funciona, dele colocar alguma cosia que não se encaixa no que definimos como algo útil e de qualidade aqui. Estes casos ou podem ser facilmente resolvidos com uma edição ou instrução simples ou eles não têm solução mesmo a não ser um fechamento simples.

Mas tem um desequilíbrio aí. Ainda que eu goste e acho que estamos fazendo mais do que devíamos para ajudar as pessoas perguntarem, o esforço maior tem que partir de quem quer ajuda e não de quem oferece ajuda.

Se alguém acha que é fácil, se discorda, ótimo, faça o seu melhor para mudar essa situação, para resolver todos os problemas. Eu vou adorar ver isto acontecendo. Só não venha fazer caridade com a minha carteira.

Comment: "Existe uma falha na escola que não mais ensina as pessoas se comunicar e resolver problemas, que são as duas coisas fundamentais que a pessoa deve saber" +1

Comment: Agora toda a gente é programador sem sequer saber escrever direito e muito menos explicar um problema.

Answer (score 8):

O bigown já deu uma resposta bem precisa, mas vou complementar demonstrando porque que poucas perguntas fechadas são reabertas. O principal motivo é que a maioria das perguntas que são fechadas não são salváveis. Não vou sair caçando links por aí, mas frequentemente surgem perguntas mais ou menos assim:

### Caso 1:

> Fala galera, e aí o que vcs acham q vale mais apena estudar? C++ ou php?
>   
>   [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

### Caso 2:

> Pessoal, eu tava vendo um tutorial aqui, mas achei que tem pokos comandos nele. Vcs sabem onde posso encontra um tutorial com mais comandos?
>   
>   [tutorial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tutorial) [comandos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comandos)

### Caso 3:

> CARA, TOU TENTANDO ENTENDER PQ TA DANDO ERRO, ALGUEM ME AJUDA POR FAVOR?
>
> ```
> Trocentas linhas de código mal-escrito, mal-identado e cheio de gambiarras.
> Os únicos comentários no código são lixo gerado automaticamente pela IDE
>    que o autor da pergunta nem se deu ao trabalho de retirar.
> Para ajudar ainda mais, o código não é compilável porque há referências a
>    um monte de classes/métodos/WTF que não estão no código postado e não
>    são parte de nenhuma biblioteca bem conhecida ou que o autor da pergunta
>    sequer tenha mencionado.
> ```
>
> [alguma-meta-tag-qualquer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alguma-meta-tag-qualquer) [alguma-tag-obscura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alguma-tag-obscura) [alguma-tag-irrelevante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alguma-tag-irrelevante) [alguma-tag-genérica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alguma-tag-gen%c3%a9rica)

### Caso 4:

> Pessoal me ajuda! Meu programa não está funcionando!
>
> ```
> Trecho de duas ou três linhas de código completamente irrelevantes.
> ```
>
> E então, alguém pode me ajudar? URGENTE!!!!
>   
>   [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [mysql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql)

### Caso 5:

> Pessoal, eu estou com um arquivo aqui e deu erro ao copiar pela rede. Alguém pode me ajudar?
>   
>   [pen-drive](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pen-drive) [rede](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rede)

### Caso 6:

> **O** *meu* `código` ****** esta da**ndo** MU**i*tus*** <sup>er**os**</sup>
>
> ```
> alguem sabe
> ```
>
> ===============
>   como
>
> #### EU posso
>
> ar**umar** Is<sup>so?</sup>
>   
>   public *class* **HelloWorld** { public ****** sta`tic vo`id ### mai<sup>n(Stri</sup>ng[] a<sub>rgs) { Syst</sub>em.out.p**rintln("Hell**o World"); ----------- } }
>   
>   [codigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codigo) [ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajuda)

### Caso 7:

> Aqui está o código:
>
> ```
> print Hello World
> ```
>
> [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [fiz-uma-pergunta-mas-não-perguntei-nada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiz-uma-pergunta-mas-n%c3%a3o-perguntei-nada)

### Caso 8:

> Ai gente, tenho que entregar isso amanhã e não consigo fazer funcionar. Ajuda ai.
>
> [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [adivinhe-o-meu-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adivinhe-o-meu-c%c3%b3digo) [os-demais-usuários-conseguem-ler-a-minha-mente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/os-demais-usu%c3%a1rios-conseguem-ler-a-minha-mente)

### Caso 9:

> boa tarde eu estou com um sistema que pega o endereço de um validador que ta na tabela e manda ele pra query, mas ta dando problema na base pq no controller o arquivo nao esta correto e daí quando vai para o relatorio nao funciona no banco do cliente remoto. Alguem tem uma idéia aí?
>   
>   [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) [cobol](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol) [algoritmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmo) [quem-entender-a-pergunta-ganha-um-doce](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quem-entender-a-pergunta-ganha-um-doce)

### Caso 10:

> [Um monte de texto incompreensível e super confuso]
>
> ```
> [Um monte de código incompreensível e super confuso]
> ```
>
> Seus bando de fdp, inves de ficar reclamando esses monte de merda nos comentarios e fechar a pergunta, pq vcs nao procuram o q fazer e respondem logo essa bosta?
>   
>   [Mais um monte de texto ininteligível]
>
> ```
> [Mais código pra lá de zoado]
> ```
>
> [Mais comentários demonstrando a "bela" educação do usuário]

### Caso 11:

> Alguem ai tem um bom tutorial de php para me indicar?
>   
>   [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

### Caso 12:

> Estou estudando programação e queria saber se alguém pode me ajudar explicando os detalhes de como é que se faz para programar em C++. Grato.
>   
>   [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [quem-conseguir-postar-uma-resposta-completa-e-detalhada-em-um-twitt-ganha-um-doce](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quem-conseguir-postar-uma-resposta-completa-e-detalhada-em-um-twitt-ganha-um-doce)

---

Bem, todos estes casos acima são horríveis e desestimulam as pessoas a responder. E, tirando as duplicatas, quase todas as perguntas fechadas que nunca são reabertas se enquadram em algum dos casos acima. E como o bigown já explicou, em muitos destes casos tentar convencer o usuário a melhorar a sua pergunta é perda de tempo. Já vi casos inclusive aonde o usuário acabou editando a pergunta para pior, retirando informações importantes ao invés de acrescentar informações importantes!

Comment: Hahaha, deu até pra rir. Parece as pérolas do SOpt, hehe. O 'URGENTE' é foda. Infelizmente a grande maioria das perguntas fechadas são assim mesmo.

Comment: Está de mais isto :D