# O que fazer com esta pergunta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Usando como referência esta pergunta do meta [Poucas perguntas são reabertas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2537/poucas-perguntas-s%C3%A3o-reabertas) o que poderia ser feito com essa pergunta: [Problema na configuração inicial do projecto da 2ª edição livro JavaEE com JSF Prime Faces e CDI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55400/7210)?

A meu ver estes pontos poderiam ser corrigidos e/ou explicados ao AP:

1 - O título deveria ser editado, parece genérico de mais e sem indicar qual o verdadeiro problema.

2 - Deveria ser sugerido ao AP que indicasse código que descrevesse o problema, as tais páginas que ele indica.

3 - Deveria indicar como consegue resolver o problema, e se existe outra forma de o resolver. (Não entendi porque é que se consegue resolver quer outra solução)

4 - Será que faz falta uma pergunta com intuito de melhorar um livro? (Parece ser a intenção do AP)

*Se encontrarem mais problemas podem indicar nos comentários.*

Agora o que fazer com esta pergunta? Indicar ao AP os problemas da pergunta? Fechar? Concordam com os meus pontos?

Answer (score 3):

Do jeito que está acho que deve ser fechada como baseada em opiniões, ou até mesmo como não clara.

Agora com suas sugestões de edição da pergunta, na minha opinião, tranquilamente se torna uma pergunta válida, principalmente com sua sugestão número 2. Pois aí, corrigindo o problema do código, ele estaria, primeiramente corrigindo seu próprio problema, e também ajudando a melhorar o livro.

Com sua sugestão 3 o autor poderia responder a própria pergunta, e ele mesmo ajudando a melhorar o livro.

Já a sugestão 4, ao meu ver, nesse caso, não me importa o objetivo final, desde que tenha a ver com programação. Pois o objetivo do site é questões e respostas que possam ser de ajuda para outros usuários que passam pelo mesmo problema.

É um típico caso que uma edição tornaria essa pergunta numa pergunta bem interessante e que poderia ajudar muitos usuários no futuro.

Assim acho que deveríamos aconselhar o AP a editar sua pergunta, principalmente seguindo a sugestão 2, pois sem essa sugestão acho que não teria muita ajuda outro usuários corrigir os outros problemas.

Comment: Então fica a pergunta. Devemos: Editar? Fechar? Aconselhar o AP? Todas em conjunto?

Comment: @JorgeB. Primeiro aconselhar o AP. Porque acho que o ponto principal é o código. Depois do código se o AP não corrigiu os outros problemas, acho que pode ser feito por nós/comunidade.

Comment: Mas não deveríamos fechar primeiro antes que comessem a surgir respostas de "eu acho"?

Comment: Acho que deveríamos, em primeiro lugar, aconselhar o AP para adicionar a parte do código onde está o problema. Caso ele não se manifeste, a pergunta deveria fechada. (Não claro)

Comment: @JorgeB. É verdade. Em outras discussões aqui no meta foi sugerido que se esperasse algum tempo pelo AP antes de fechar. Mas eu discordo pelo motivo que você deu, de aparecer respostas do tipo "eu acho". Então acho que sim, deveria ser fechada, e se corrigida, reaberta novamente.

Comment: @emanuelsn Eu compartilhava da sua opinião. Mas ao analisar ponto do JorgeB. ele tem razão. Se esperarmos esse tempo, pode ser que alguém responda com "eu acho". Aí depois se o AP editar a pergunta, pode ser que aquelas respostas fiquem fora do contexto da pergunta editada. O problema de dar tempo ao AP, implica também em dar tempo para respostas que depois fiquem inválidas.

Comment: @Earendul é mesmo a esse ponto que eu queria chegar...

Comment: Acho que estamos 'entre a cruz e a espada'. Se indicarmos para fechar, acho que ela será fechada e é possível que ela não será reaberta (assim como já mencionado pelo @JorgeB. na sua pergunta linkada na postagem inicial). Mas, dando tempo ao AP, concordo que daríamos tempo para as respostas-opiniões.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendo do "processo", o ideal é sinalizar e/ou votar nas respostas ruins. Não acho justo penalizar o AP pelas eventuais respostas ruins.

Comment: Eu também havia respondido, mas como eu concordo com essa resposta eu removi a minha. :)